# Using ContentProviders for non persistent data

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I could use a little bit of help understanding `ContentProviders`

**Problem:**

- I've got a list of entities (`String`s) which should be displayed in an activity.
- The information are provided by third party apps. And are only valid as long as the application is running.
- Each app will get its own activity to display their data.

**Solution:**

- I provide a `ContentProvider`.

**Question:**

Do I have to use a DB as underlying persistence? As an alternative I could use a plain `ArrayList<String>` to store the entities and use separate `ContentProvider` for each application.

The reason I'm asking is that the complete interface and infrastructure seams to be focused to transport *persistent data* with use of DBs. So I'm wondering whether I misuse the framework.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use an in-memory SQLite database if you so wish - this would last for the life-time of your application containing the provider however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you definitely do not need to use a Database -- you are free to implement whatever storage mechanism you want (or lack of).  Most of the time, however, it seems you'll have a backing database in your application so things are persisted.